# user "example" was not authenticated (Peer)

Tags: sql, postgresql, authentication

Hello I have such users in my db [image]

I want to delete user `postgres` so I

```
DROP USER postgres;
```

I get the error

```
ERROR:  current user cannot be dropped
```

After this I try to switch on another user:

```
postgres=# \connect postgres andrey
```

and I get the error

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "andrey"
```

Comment: I post the literal Russian error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error message is self-explanatory.

To connect as `andrey`, you'll have to edit `pg_hba.conf` and add a line like the following at the very top:

```
local postgres andrey trust
```

Then reload the configuration with

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

and you will be able to login as user `andrey`.

But it is impossible to drop the “bootstrap superuser” `postgres`. I don't see why that is necessary though. You need a superuser, and if you don't like the name `postgres` for some reason, you can rename it.

But my advice is to leave user `postgres` with that name – it is customary to name the bootstrap superuser `postgres`.